# What would the Japanese equivalent of "Order!" be when gaveling?

Tags: word-requests

What's the Japanese equivalent of the "Order!" shouted when a judge or speaker of the house gavels their assemblies?

Comment: According to this link they don't use a gavel in Japanese courthouses but as shown in the answer at least it's used in fiction https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1053992530

Comment: Oh, I didn't know gavels are actually used in the US. I always believed it's a purely fictional thing.

Comment: @naruto すみません、that is amusing to hear for an American. We also have tv shows with (fake?) judges.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 静粛に【せいしゅくに】！

or "Be silent!" is the most appropriate answer, I think.

(Although it's from a game, [逆転裁判　【ぎゃくてんさいばん】](https://youtu.be/d6Qyf-psi90?t=10m20s), I don't believe it's far off from the real thing.)

Answer (score 12):

[This video](https://youtu.be/HJm19MGRiDI?t=55) is a live broadcast of the Diet in Japan.
The next line was told by the Speaker of the House to have the members be quiet. (Siikamiika tells us a more clear sound source [here](https://youtu.be/qIG4-BdXRnE?t=70).)

> ご静粛｛せいしゅく｝に願｛ねが｝います！

Comment: I also found [this other video](https://youtu.be/qIG4-BdXRnE?t=1m8s), I think you can hear the word more clearly in it. Is there a difference between うるさい！ and 静粛に願います, politeness-wise? :P

Comment: @siikamiika: 「うるさい！」と「静粛に願います」とは静かにして欲しいという意味では同じですが、「うるさい！」と言ったあとには 喧嘩｛けんか｝ がはじまる可能性があります。

Comment: Yes there is. うるさいis just literally "so noisy" with the implied meaning and tone of "Shut up!". 静粛に願いますis actually quite formal, having used a pretty advanced noun (静粛) and 願います; I'd translate this as "I ask for tranquility" -- which is more formal than even "Quiet please" （お静かに）.

Comment: Yeah, I just meant that it would probably be worth it to add that information to the answer especially because this appears to be a Hot Network Question

Comment: @siikamiika I can do that, but tell me exactly what you want to add, or edit it yourself :)

Comment: @GabbyQuattrone Your answer is fine as it is because it offers an alternative viewpoint to the question: court in Japanese fiction. I just suggested that mackygoo would improve their answer by mentioning the politeness aspect of 静粛に願います when compared to the うるさい also heard on the video that I linked. Technically it would be [so-so](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) to translate mackygoo's comment and add it to their answer but generally edits should only improve post's formatting and such without changing the actual message.